# Downgrade Android SDK( api 23 -> api 21)

Tags: android, gradle, sdk

Due to some problems with permissions in SDK API 23 (Marshmallow) I wanted to switch back to API 21, yet I'm encountering some issues... I've read so many posts  with similiar problems and tried (almost I guess) everything: I've updated all SDK Build/Platform Tools, features for API 21, Suport and Repository Libraries. Then I've cleaned up the project, rebuilt it and synchronized. Yet, I'm getting those errors:
[image]

My build.gradle looks like following:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.pablo.appcontacts"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

I'm not very familiar with this, can anybody help me to fix this cause I really can't find a way to..?

Comment: "Due to some problems with permissions in SDK API 23 (Marshmallow) I wanted to switch back to API 21" -- that won't solve any of your problems. The `compileSdkVersion`, libraries, etc. have nothing to do with [the runtime permission problems you are encountering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34095129/android-frustrating-permissions). `targetSdkVersion` does, but you do not have to change anything else in your app to reduce your `targetSdkVersion` to 22 or something.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok, thank you, I didn't know that.

Comment: For more information, see [our blog post on compileSdkVersion vs targetSdkVersion](https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd)

Answer (score 4):

3 Steps:

1 Edit build.grade

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.stackoverflow.answer"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

2 Sync gradle button

3 Rebuild project

Comment: It's nice, but I think not totally correct. I also needed to add the lines to the repository support in dependencies, otherwise I was getting some errors about missing resources in `styles.xml`.

Comment: But that changes @PawełPoręba depends for the android version, each version has differents options.